# Using Tim2 inside interrupt handler for STM32F1

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32f4, nucleo, stm32f0

I am blinking LED using TIM2 General timer.
**Code in main.c**

```
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2);

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim){
    if(htim->Instance==TIM2){
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, LED_Pin);
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked EXTI interrupt should be called to blink the led faster 20 times. However, LED stays on and stops blinking at all.

```
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
}

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin){
    if(GPIO_Pin == BT_Pin){
        for(volatile int i=20; i>0; i--){
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, LED_Pin);
            HAL_Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please advice how can i adjust interrupt ISR for EXTI so it will use TIM2 as well with faster blinking.

Comment: Not related, but the use of `volatile` here is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

`HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback()` runs in the interrupt context - it is not appropriate to flash the indicator there much less include a delay.  No other code while run while in the interrupt, and `HAL_Delay()` is probably not interrupt safe in any case.

Instead, in the button handler, set a down-counter to be decremented in the timer handler, and in the timer handler set the reload depending on the down-counter being zero or not.  Something like this:

[I have not included the HAL calls to do the `TODO`'s above, because I'd have to look them up, but that is the outline.]

```
volatile unsigned fast_flash_count = 0 ;

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if(htim->Instance==TIM2)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, LED_Pin);

        if( fast_flash_count > 0 )
        {
            fast_flash_count-- ;

            // Set TIM2 reload to fast-flash period
            TODO
        }
        else
        {
            // Set TIM2 reload to slow-flash period
            TODO
        }
    }
}

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    if(GPIO_Pin == BT_Pin)
    {
        fast_flash_count = 20 ;

        // Set TIM2 counter to current reload value 
        // to force immediate interrupt
        TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is how i've adjusted TIM callback function. `if(htim->Instance==TIM2)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, LED_Pin);

        if( fast_flash_count > 0 )
        {
            htim2.Init.Period = 299;
     for(volatile int x = fast_flash_count; x>0; x-- ){
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, LED_Pin);
     }
     fast_flash_count =0;
     htim2.Init.Period = 499;
        }` But still does not work :(